# Why has this question on SO been closed and not moved?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, closed-questions

Two days ago I answered an Excel question on SO: "[How do I get to display the last date that has a corresponding value in another column in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067754/how-do-i-get-to-display-the-last-date-that-has-a-corresponding-value-in-another-c/6069282#6069282)"

Now I found that it was closed yesterday as off topic. OK, when I think about it, it is, because its not programming related, it was solvable with a worksheet formula. But I spend some effort into that answer and I think its not trivial, and Superuser would be a good place for it.

Now to my question, why has it been closed and not moved? I think its clearly a not easy Excel question and has a value. Would it be possible reopen and to move it now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a question be useful and closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88550/how-can-a-question-be-useful-and-closed)

Comment: The rule (well guideline) on off topic posts is that if you're not 100% sure it's on topic for somewhere else **don't** migrate it.

Comment: I can confirm that Excel formulas, while brutish and loud-spoken, are indeed programming.  :-)

Comment: Your work is not lost. The question is still there, along with your answer. And because closed questions are not necessarily locked, that means people can still *vote* on your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't find this question of sufficient quality to be migrated -- it was not clearly asked and a borderline "do my work for me".

The general rule is, questions are only migrated if they are *quality* questions. Or stated another way, "not crap".